# Codeigniter causing mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I would like to check whether r.is_show_map = 1, if true, then return r.lat, otherwise, return null

Here is the code

```
  $this->db->select('r.*, IF(r.is_show_map = 1, r.lat, null) as r.lat', false);
```

The problem is it caused the syntax error

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.lat FROM (`request` as r) WHERE `r`.`adv_type` != 0 AND `r`.`is_delete` = 0 AN' at line 1

SELECT r.*, IF(r.is_show_map = 1, r.lat, null) as r.lat FROM (`request` as r) WHERE `r`.`adv_type` != 0 AND `r`.`is_delete` = 0 AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(r.create_date, INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the manual? What is the error number associated to?

Comment: yes just remove the alias and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('r.*, IF(r.is_show_map = 1, r.lat, null) as lat', false);
```

Comment: I wonder if I select r.* and r.lat at the same time, then what would be the final result , is the r.lat prior to the r.lat  in r.*? thanks

Comment: @user782104 `f I select r.* and r.lat at the same time, then what would be the final result ` - field r.lat will be duplicated in the result. "is the r.lat prior to the r.lat in r.*" - what do you mean by the word "prior"? First in order? Id depends upon the order you put them in the query.

Comment: that means r.* , r.lat , then the final result will be r.lat instead of r.lat inside r.*?

Comment: yes there are two lat in the result, which one will be the final result?

Comment: @user782104 Actually, both of them are final result. It would be better to rename the second `lat` - alias of IF to some other name to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: sorry if I just get "lat" (although there are duplicate result in the query), then which one is select actually?

Comment: @user782104 Sorry, it's hard to answer your question about the duplicates without more information. Please, prepare a new new question with an sqlfiddle with sample data and the query, that you run. Then explain, what you need to get. I think, you'll get a meaningful answer.